# Coding an Image Vectorization Program

Tags: graphics, vector, svg, geometry

I am wondering how you would code an image vectorization program, al la vectormagic.com? Where would you even begin and would it be possible to create in any web based programming languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behind vectorization programs are complex algorithms (for basic outline look on quite nice paper [depixelizing pixel art](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kopf/pixelart/) by guys at Microsoft). 
Anyway, it's possible to write almost in any language, that can process images, but those complex algorithms are pretty system resources expensive. So web based languages are quite inappropriate for that type of task.